# Syntax error when creating procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this query.

```
SELECT distinct c.reportingDate, c.clientId
FROM clients AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM accounts_europe AS e
        WHERE e.reportingDate = c.reportingDate
          AND e.clientId = c.clientId

        union

        SELECT 1 -- line A. unexpected select error
        FROM accounts_usa AS u
        WHERE u.reportingDate = c.reportingDate
          AND u.clientId = c.clientId
      ) ;
```

when executing it at mysql workbench it displays a syntax error which says "unexpected select" at line A.

However, since the query is right, when I execute it, it indeed executes and returns the correct results.

When I try to create a procedure that contains the exact same thing, it cannot be compiled. The source code is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_sample`()
BEGIN
    SELECT distinct c.reportingDate, c.clientId
    FROM clients AS c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
          ( SELECT 1
            FROM accounts_europe AS e
            WHERE e.reportingDate = c.reportingDate
              AND e.clientId = c.clientId

            union

            SELECT 1 -- line A. unexpected select error
            FROM accounts_usa AS u
            WHERE u.reportingDate = c.reportingDate
              AND u.clientId = c.clientId
          ) ;
END
```

The message displayed is "The object's DDL statement contains syntax errors." 
Is it something I am doing wrong about this or is it a bug of the mysql workbench?

Comment: What version of mysql workbench are you using?

Comment: @ConradLotz the latest, 6.3.10

Comment: Where exactly do you see the syntax error? I just tried the SELECT statement and it displays in the SQL IDE without any error (WB 6.3.10).

Comment: @MikeLischke at the line A as shown at the code above

Comment: What I meant was: where in Workbench do so that error?

Comment: @MikeLischke In the workbench editor, if I understood correctly your question and also a message was popping up when I was trying to execute the create procedure statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes up because of a MySQL grammar bug* that has been fixed meanwhile. Try the latest Workbench version instead (currently WB 8.0.11 RC, see "Development Releases" on the download page). That should work for you.

(*) MySQL Workbench uses ANTLR4 for parsing SQL code. That requires a MySQL grammar to generate the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct syntactically. It's maybe a workbench's bug. Coming to Stored Procedure, you should be able to create it with that query. Try creating SP using below query. In my case, I am able to create SP using this. Copy this query open a new query editor in the workbench and paste it there, select all and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

```
USE `YOUR_DB`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `proc_sample`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `YOUR_DB`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `proc_sample`()
BEGIN
    SELECT distinct c.reportingDate, c.clientId
    FROM clients AS c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
          ( SELECT 1
            FROM accounts_europe AS e
            WHERE e.reportingDate = c.reportingDate
              AND e.clientId = c.clientId

            union

            SELECT 1
            FROM accounts_usa AS u
            WHERE u.reportingDate = c.reportingDate
              AND u.clientId = c.clientId
          ) ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```